# How to append data to a JSON using loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I m trying to append data to a json file using loops but getting error as ***json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)***

What's the correct way of adding the data here

```
import json

for i in range(10):

    with open("sample_file.json", "a+") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        data.update(i)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, file)
```

The file s**ample_file.json** contains some dummy text as 12345

Comment: If you need to gather different data together and append it to a JSON file, try creating a list/dict, then iterate over the data add append it to the list/dict. At the end, dump that list/dict into a JSON file. It is a bit hard to understand what you want to do in that piece of code.

Comment: just want to add 1- 10 to json file so that can read later

Comment: it has some dummy text

Comment: It is still not clear from your question what you want to accomplish. If you explain it better it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @nonDucor `12345` is a valid JSON number, and `json.load(open('tmp.json'))` will return `12345` if that's the entire contents of the file.

Comment: Note, though, that `json.load` does *not* parse JSON streams; it expects the file to contain a *single* JSON value, whether that vale is a number, string, object, array, or null.

Comment: The immediate problem, though, is that opening a file in `a+` mode leaves the file pointer at the *end* of the file; there's nothing for `json.load` to read. You would need to seek first, then read, then write.

Comment: However, that's going to read the entire file, then *append* the updated version to the end, effectively doubling the contents of the file on each iteration. If you are going to simply append to the file, there's no reason to read its contents first.

Answer (score 0):

your json file should have `[]` or `{}` this in the file.
[image]